# Are there Disassembler for Mac which supports scripting

Tags: disassembly, disassemblers

Are there any disassemblers for Mac that comes in freeware. I have installed radare2 but finding difficult to use.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend capstone disassembler, it supports multiple architectures. Pydasm is also quite simple and nice disassembler.

Answer (score 1):

Pydasm is outdated, wrong on many cases, so do not go for that.

Capstone is definitely the best choice now, and works on MacOS very well.